# Cache Picasso Images in background

Tags: android, picasso

I'm fetching some data in the background to cache so my feed is always updated, but I'm having an issue with the Images. Right now images won't cache unless they have already been loaded onto the imageview. I'm wondering if there is a way to  load/cache the images in the background?

Comment: Just use a new Thread to load them.But it's memory waste.

Comment: Picasso does that job for you, it loads the image and then cache it. There's no point in caching something that did not show up. It's memory waste as user "tiny sunlight" said.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for [`fetch()`](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#fetch--).

`picasso.load(something).fetch()` will warm the cache for you.

Answer (score 0):

How far I think you can use new `ImageView` for this. Once cached, then get the Image from the `ImageView`.

Code :

```
 ImageView mImageView = new ImageView();
 Picasso.with(rootView.getContext()).load("your file").into(mImageView);
 Bitmap mBitmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
```

then use the bitmap. Thanks.

Comment: That is quite a waste of an ImageView.